# Upload folders to server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My apologies because my first post did not meet the standards of the site

I replay my issue

Am  trying to upload a folder with more than 200 files with JavaScript & php. The issue is that it’s just upload 21 files and stops after that showing the issue: undefined index 21.

my html file : home.html

```
<form method="POST" id="upload_folder_form">
    <div class="row">
       <input class="action" type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
       <input class="parent_id" type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="0">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="nom">Folder</label>

           <input id="files[]" type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control"  webkitdirectory multiple>

       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn color-cmc pull-right" name="btn_envoi">
                      <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Import
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

my Javascripy file : Folder.js

```
$('#upload_folder_form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //récuperation des variables
        let form = $('#upload_folder_form');
        let action = $('.action').val();
        let parent_id = $('.parent_id').val();
        let redirect = "http://localhost/archivia/app/controllers/FolderController.php";

        const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
        let size = files.length;
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('action', action);
        formData.append('parent_id', parent_id);
        formData.append('size', size);

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let file = files[i];
            let fileParamName = `file${i}`;
            let filePathParamName = `filepath${i}`;
            formData.append(fileParamName, file);
            formData.append(filePathParamName, file.webkitRelativePath);
        }

        axios.post(redirect, formData).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result.data);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

My Php file : FolderController.php

```
function upload(){
    $path = "../../public/Archives CMC/";
    $size = $_POST['size'];

    var_dump($_FILES);

    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
        $folderpath = $path.dirname($_POST['filepath'.$i]);
        $file = $_FILES['file'.$i];
        $filename = $file['name'];
        $file_tmp = $file["tmp_name"];

        if (file_exists($path.$folderpath)){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path.$folderpath.'/'.$filename);
        }else{
            mkdir($path.$folderpath,0644,true);
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path.$folderpath.'/'.$filename);
        }

    }


}
```

For a folder that gots more than 30 files, juste 20 will be uploaded

How can I come over it please???

Thanks

Comment: _“My apologies because my first post did not meet the standards of the site”_ - next time, please _edit_ your already existing version of the question then, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: So what does `var_dump($_FILES);` show, actually a `print_r($_FILES);` may be easier to read

Comment: Did you read the warning about webkitdirectory ___Non-standard

This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future___

Comment: @RiggsFolly  let me show you with images

Comment: Maybe you should just read @CBroe answer. Seems the most obvious reason

Comment: @RiggsFolly Am sorry, i don't know how to post images on this site !!!!

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks i notice that.. I will do my best

Comment: [file19] => Array
        (
            [name] => c7.JPG
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\phpDF3C.tmp
       <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: file20 in C:\wamp64\www\archivia\app\Controllers\FolderController.php on line <i>82</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry i dont know how to upload images can u help me with the few informations i give please!!!!

Comment: Text is almost always better than pictures anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a configuration setting, that limits how many file uploads will be accepted in such a POST request.

It’s named `max_file_uploads`, and the default value is `20`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads

Note that the “changeable mode” is shown as PHP_INI_SYSTEM there - which means, it can only be set in set in php.ini or httpd.conf. So if you are not in control of the server, you will have to ask your server admin / hosting provider, if they can change this for you.

This is also mentioned in the [common pitfalls](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) sub-chapter of the explanation of how file uploads work,

> As of PHP 5.2.12, the max_file_uploads configuration setting controls the maximum number of files that can uploaded in one request. **If more files are uploaded than the limit, then $_FILES will stop processing files once the limit is reached.** For example, if max_file_uploads is set to 10, then $_FILES will never contain more than 10 items.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of PHP parameters that act roughly together in this area

```
// the max number of file that PHP will accept from upload
// as it cannot know how many the browser is sending until it gets them
// php just Stops processing at this number of files
max_file_uploads = 20

// the max size of any one file that will be accepted
upload_max_filesize = 2M

// as files are transmitted using POST, this param should also be checked
// it should be large enough to cope with all the files uploaded
// So basic calc, assuming all files wont be the max size would be

// post_max_size = max_file_uploads  * upload_max_filesize 
//
// However you also have to make room for all the normal html form parameters 
// that may come as well as the file(s)
//
// so 
// post_max_size = max_file_uploads  * upload_max_filesize + 8M as a guestimate
post_max_size = 8M    

// of course as all this will occupy memory in PHP while it processes all the
// files and other field inputs it should be large enough to cope with 
// all the file and of course some room for the program code
memory_limit = 128M
```

***Ignore the numbers in these params, they are just placeholders, not my suggestions for your system, those you will have to work out for yourself***

> As you are using WAMPServer you have access to amend all these parameters in the `php.ini` file. However, a **warning**, if you intend to move this code to a shared hosting eventually, you may not have access to these parameters. So be careful when designing a system with large requirements, it may force you to spend more on the eventual home of this code.

> And finally, when you change these parameters in the `php.ini` file, remember to bounce Apache so the new values get picked up.

```
wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration->Restart Service
```