# Does httpd.conf override php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, httpd.conf

I am working on a symfony project and I'm doing some multiple file uploads. I run my app on a local apache server with wamp64.

My problem was that I couldn't upload multiple file because I was exceeding the limit of 83886080 bytes which is the default limit in the php.ini.

So I went to edit my php.ini file and the change appear to be ignored. I still had the same issue despite editing post_max_size, upload_max_size etc.
I ran phpinfo (); and I was editing the good php.ini so I was clueless.

After many research I couldn't find any answers to my problem. So I tried many things and I finally came across this "httpd.conf" file and I found that it had a ThreadStackSize of 83886080 (bytes). I edited this with 20000000 instead and now it's working.

I was wondering if i did something wrong or if someone could explain me what is going on.

Comment: WAMPServer has 2 `php.ini` files. Use the wampmanager menu `wampmanager->PHP->php.ini` to make sure you edit the one that is used by the Apache webserver and the PHP that runs within it

Comment: I have never had to change the `ThreadStackSize` If you find you have edited the wrong `php.ini` file, change that back

Comment: But the thing is that i used the wampmanager menu to edit the php.ini file but it didn't changed anything i still had the same issue.

Comment: What was the original error you were getting

Comment: POST Content-Length of 15755770 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes

Comment: Oh yes it does i didn't noticed that

Comment: Are the numbers in the error message now the same or larger then original error? I mean did you just not increase the buffers enough. You might like to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65936605/2310830) it attempts to describe how these parameters interact with each other

Comment: I edit back the httpd.conf file to it's original content and i still get the same error : "Warning: POST Content-Length of 57769773 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0" (my pot_max_size is at 64M)

Comment: ``max_file_uploads = 21, upload_max_filesize = 20M, memory_limit = 2048M, post_max_size = 64M``

Comment: Also now, post_max_size say it's 8M on phpinfo()

Comment: `post_max_size` has to be large enough to have all the 21 files * 20M file size plus some for all the other stuff like other fields that may also be sent in the POST. So try `post_max_size = 450M`

Comment: It's still doesn't working i dont know..

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say the value are set to now. You do realise you need to RESTART Apache after each change to the `php.ini` i assume?

Comment: Yes of course, i did it every time. Now it is back to 8M it doesn't make any sense

Comment: You are right, it does not make sense. Can you make sure that there is only ONE of these parameters in the `php.ini` as if there are 2 the seconf will just overwrite the first

Comment: 1. Can you post your `php.ini` on a file share? 2. What version of Apache and PHP are you using. I will try your `php.ini` on my WAMPServer

Comment: Okay, i made i php.ini file in the root of my symfony project, added the line that i wanted ``max_input_time=60
memory_limit=256M
post_max_size=64M
upload_max_filesize=64M
max_file_uploads=20``
And now it's working !

Comment: In the root of your Symfony project? That too makes no sense, it should be called `phpForApache.ini` and live in the `php\phpz.y.z` folder and have a symlink to it in the `Apache/apache2.4.x/bin` folder

Comment: Found here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/cloud/languages/php.html#default-php-ini-values

Comment: So you are using the PHP builtin web server and NOT WAMPServer for what you are doing

Comment: Ohh ok that's make sense, i though the symfony server was working with wamp my bad

Comment: No they are **COMPLETELY** different animals :) Its not using Apache either so your `ThreadStackSize` change makes even less sense